# When to use LSTM vs Lasso/Ridge Regression vs ARIMA?

Tags: arima, model-selection, lasso, lstm, ridge-regression

I have a set of N time series and want to make predictions about the future values of these N elementary time signals.

From a first rough analysis, I can say that at a given moment in time, the N time signals are related to, maybe even correlated with each other.

I am unsure which technique would be a suitable approach for this kind of constellation.

In general:

would it make sense to make forecasts with a LSTM technique or would it be better to use approaches like lasso/ridge regression or things like ARIMA (am I missing a technique?).

What would be the assumptions when using each of these techniques?